# Why does the water dissociation constant Kw remains constant?

Tags: physical-chemistry, thermodynamics, equilibrium

At $\pu{25 ^\circ C}$ at equilibrium the value of $K_\mathrm{w}$ is $\pu{1\times 10^{-14} M}$ and the concentration of $\ce{H+}$ and $\ce{OH-}$ is equal i.e. $\pu{1\times 10^{-7} M}$.

Now if we add $\ce{HCl}$ to it the $\ce{HCl}$ will form $\ce{H3O+}$ and so the concentration of $\ce{H+}$ increases and so the equilibrium shifts towards the left to counteract the changes. As a result the concentration of $\ce{OH-}$ decreases but why does still the $K_\mathrm{w}$ stays the same. If we add too much $\ce{HCl}$ such as 1 mole then we know it will completely dissociate and would form $\ce{H3O+}$ whose concentration would be $\pu{1 M}$.

So now what will happen to $K_\mathrm{w}$? Does it still remains constant but why? Does still the concentration of $\ce{H+}$ can not rise above $1\times 10^{-14}$ but why?

Comment: $K_w$ is not really an absolute constant. It depends on the ionic strength of the solution as well as the temperature. In chemistry problems it is typically regarded as an absolute constant because (1) close is generally good enough for most chemistry problems and (2) if a viral expression was used the mathematics would get too complicated to solve by hand.

Comment: @ Moon. I do not understand your question. You ask "why the concentration of $\ce{H+}$ cannot rise above $10^{-14}$? " Well. The concentration can of course be higher than $10^{-14}$ . In pure water, this concentration is $10^{-7}$, which is much higher than $10^{-14}$ !!!

Comment: See Wikipedia's article [Self-ionization of water](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Self-ionization_of_water).

Comment: I've rollbacked the edit to the previous version.Your newer edit is better asked as a new question as it negates the answers provided.. the question changed from explanation of ionisation constant to how addition of acids and bases affects the ionisation constant.

Comment: @Safdar okay  so i  will ask it as a separate question

Comment: For formatting, See [here](https://chemistry.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/443/which-symbols-are-written-in-roman-upright-font-and-which-are-italicized) and [here](https://chemistry.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/86/how-can-i-format-math-chemistry-expressions-here?noredirect=1&lq=1). For a more detailed MathJax guide, look [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference), [minor other details](https://chemistry.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3044/hidden-points-of-editing-you-probably-didnt-know?noredirect=1&lq=1)

Comment: You can also add breaks between paragraphs by creating a gap between the 2 paragraphs which makes it easier to read than one block of text.

Answer (score 4):

Your question reflects your knowledge in chemistry so I'll try to keep this explanation simple as possible.

Water conduct electricity because it contains $\ce{H+}$ and $\ce{OH-}$ ions by auto-ionization:

$$\ce{H2O <=> H+ + OH- \tag1}$$

It has been defined that this ionization is a constant at $\pu{25 ^\circ C}$. Thus by definition:

$$K_\mathrm{w} = [\ce{H+}][\ce{OH-}] = 1.0 \times 10^{-14} \tag2$$

Accordingly, by definition for pure water, $ [\ce{H+}]=[\ce{OH-}]= 1.0 \times 10^{-7}$. And then, there is a widely accepted principle in chemistry called Le Chatelier’s principle:

> Le Chatelier’s principle is an observation about chemical equilibria of reactions. It states that changes in the temperature, pressure, volume, or concentration of a system will result in predictable and opposing changes in the system in order to achieve a new equilibrium state.

Accordingly, increasing the concentration of reactants (species on left hand side of the reaction) will drive the reaction to the right (more products), while increasing the concentration of products (species on right hand side of the reaction) will drive the reaction to the left (more reactants). At constant temperature, even though concentrations of species (e.g., here they are $\ce{H+}$ and $\ce{OH-}$ in equation $(1)$) at new  equilibrium state is changed, the equilibrium constant remains same. In other word, the equilibrium constant is depends only on temperature.

According to Le Chatelier’s principle, in in equation $(1)$, if you add more $\ce{H+}$ or $\ce{OH-}$ (RHS), the equilibrium would be adjusted to reduce that amount by making more water. But since this addition is at constant temperature, $K_\mathrm{w}$ remains constant.

Answer (score 3):

It can be said that at the given temperature, the rate of the water autodissociation is constant, but the rate of the ion recombination is proportional to $[\ce{H+}][\ce{OH-}]$. As it is proportional to probability two such ions meet each other, because the reaction rate is limited by diffusion. According to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Self-ionization_of_water),

> The inverse recombination reaction   $\ce{H3O+ + OH− -> 2 H2O}$ is among the fastest chemical reactions known, with a reaction rate constant of $\pu{1.3×10^11 M−1 s−1}$ at room temperature. Such a rapid rate is characteristic of a diffusion-controlled reaction, in which the rate is limited by the speed of molecular diffusion.

The kinetics of the [H+] change is like:

$$\frac{\mathrm{d}[\ce{H+}]}{\mathrm{d}t} = k_1 - k_2[\ce{H+}][\ce{OH-}]$$
where $$K_\mathrm{w} = \frac{k_1}{k_2}$$ and $$k_1 = k_{1\mathrm{a}}[\ce{H2O}]$$

implying $[\ce{H2O}] \simeq \pu{55 mol/L}$ is constant.

The consequence is the product of ion concentrations at equilibrium must be constant.

If $[\ce{H+}][\ce{OH-}] \gt K_\mathrm{w}$, then ions recombine faster then water dissociates until it is equal.

If $[\ce{H+}][\ce{OH-}] \lt K_\mathrm{w}$, then water dissociates faster then ions recombine until it is equal.

The ionic strength and activity coefficients, or major presence of other non-ionic compounds complicate the thing, but the above as the general principle of chemical equilibriums remains.

Answer (score 3):

User [Mathew Mahindaratne's answer](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/a/139122/22102) is excellent, but I'd like to belabor a point. The equilibrium is given by the chemical equation:

$$\ce{H2O <=> H+ + OH- \tag1}$$

and the mathematical equation is normally reduced to:

$$K_\mathrm{w} = [\ce{H+}][\ce{OH-}] = 1.0 \times 10^{-14} \tag2$$

However thinking about equilibrium expressions in general you can see that the mathematical expression for (1) should be:

$$K^*_\mathrm{w} =\dfrac{[\ce{H+}][\ce{OH-}]}{[\ce{H2O}]}\tag{3}$$

The point here is that for *dilute* aqueous solutions that $[\ce{H2O}]$ is a constant and hence:

$$K_\mathrm{w} = [\ce{H2O}]\times K^*_\mathrm{w} = [\ce{H+}][\ce{OH-}]\tag{4}$$

Thus solutions with significant amounts of some miscible organic solvent are not "dilute aqueous" solutions, and mathematical equation (2) won't hold. This is not to say that mathematical equation (3) would be significantly better, but rather tying to create some understanding of why the simple equilibrium expressions fail.

Comment: That is why in solutions with negative pH the pH and pOH are not equal to 14 and their equilibrium constant value is also different. Please correct me if i am wrong .

Comment: @Moon - yes and no. For pH <0, or >14, you must have a very strong acid or base. Thus when dissolving HCl in water the most important effect isn't the change in the $[\ce{H2O}]$, but rather the increase in the ionic strength.

Comment: Yes MaxW we need very strong acid such as as 12 M of HCl has pH -1.08 . MaxW i want to ask you a question that in case of negative pH do we have an equilibrium  between water ,H+ and OH- ions ? And in the end you talked about ionic strength . Do you mean an increase in ionic strength of water i.e. the conectration of H+ and OH- ions become more than 1×10^{-14} M

Comment: @Moon - See wikipedia's article on [ionic strength](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ionic_strength)